# wait for user action in Selenium?

Tags: php, unit-testing, selenium, selenium-ide

```
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=login</td>
    <td>aaa</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>click</td>
    <td>id=password</td>
    <td>bbb</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>type</td>
    <td>id=captcha</td>
    <td>sdfgsdfg</td>
</tr>
```

is possible add for this Selenium IDE test for PHP, waiting for user action? i would like type captcha

Comment: look at this article http://stevebywater.blogspot.com/2008/01/selenium-and-captcha.html

Comment: thanks, please add new answer :)

Comment: Is that article solved your issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try prompt a text box for user to enter the text in the captcha, and store in variable

example:

```
storeEval | prompt(“Enter Captcha:”) | varName
```

Then type the varName text in to your captcha text box example

```
type | id=CaptchaText | ${varName}
```